# Windows 8 partition does not boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, boot-repair

I am unable to boot my Windows 8 partition,  I have tried using boot repair several times. I no longer see the EFI folder in my Windows partition.

I have tried editing the 40_custom file:

```
menuentry "Windows 8 Recovery" {
   set root='(hd0,gpt2)'`
   chainloader /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
}

}

menuentry "Windows 8" {
   set root='(hd0,gpt4)'`
   chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Microsoft Windows Vista/7/8 x86_64 UEFI-GPT" {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod fat
  insmod search_fs_uuid
  insmod chain
  search --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1 1ce5-7f28
  chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

This is the list of the partitions: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5984434/.

Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2):

```
    error: can't find command drivemap.
    error: invalid EFI file path
```

Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4):

```
    error: can't find command drivemap.
    error: invalid EFI file path
```

Both Ubuntu and Windows were installed in UEFI mode.If anyone has any ideas on how I can access my windows partition, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have installed ubuntu in legacy mode & windows is installed with UEFI. You need to change the mode accordingly in BIOS

Comment: Maybe wrong quotes on the set root = ,or maybe add the $root to the path?   chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't type `sudo update-grub` after editing `40_custom`, do so. Those edits won't take effect until you update the `grub.cfg` file by typing `sudo update-grub`. Thereafter, you should see three new entries, one for each of the stanzas you've defined. Try them all.

If that doesn't work, try using the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) If it enables you to boot both Windows and Linux, install the Debian package version in Ubuntu.

Comment: I did update the grub and all the entries show up I just cannot access them they give a disk not found error. I will try the boot manager or install another linux partition and try that.

Comment: The two names you specified ("Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2)" and "Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)" are not the same ones in your `40_custom` file. Furthermore, the errors you report include `can't find command drivemap`; but the `drivemap` command is not used in your `40_custom` file entries. This makes me think that you either did *not* type `sudo update-grub` or it didn't work right for some reason.